# Data in 2 Tablix to be summed in a 3rd

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to add two fields from two different tablix's in a 3rd tablix. The same dataset for all.

I've tried using field referencing, custom code, variables, but I can't get anything to work.  ...Fustrated...

```
Tablix14, Group4, field name "KPB_MANDEX", Value of 1st field:  =Sum(Fields!KPB_EX_VALUE.Value)
Tablix17, Group5, field name "KPB_OPTEX", Value of 2nd field:  =Sum(Fields!KPB_EX_VALUE.Value)

Tablix19, Group6, Sum of above fields:  =(ReportItems ("KPB_MANDEX") .Value) + (ReportItems ("KPB_OPTEX") .Value)
```

With this method I get a blank resultant row where the total should be.

What else should I try??  I've been googling...it seems like this should be a simple task.  Thank you in advance for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the same dataset for each tablix, design your report using one tablix and then you can use "reportitems". See attached example below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SuperSimmer44!  I was able to accomplish my task with one tablix afterall.  I believe the groups were throwing me off when I'd first attempted it.  I've got my solution - I appreciate your time!